# What would be the best word to define myself?

Tags: single-word-requests

I work for a Team of Local Guides. My job is to read the customer's email requests, schedule everything and inform the guides. Can I define myself as a "coordinator", "orchestrator" or "organizator". English is not my first language so I don't know  the right word for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're a coordinator to me. Orchestrator is a little grandiose in my opinion. Organizator isn't a word. Organizer is, but coordinator is the more usual term for someone who organizes other people's schedules.

Comment: Use ***coordinator*** if you want to big yourself up, otherwise ***secretary***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how big your functional structure, you can be called a **"coordinator"** as mentioned in comments, or simply a **"foreman"** (gender neutral form = supervisor)

[**foreman**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreman) - a person in charge of a group of workers, a particular operation, or a section of a plant.

Comment: yes, we are a small group, so foreman also works. It's right to say "travel foreman" or "tours foreman"